# My discord bot does not let a command run while the command is currently running

Tags: python, discord, command, bots, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a discord bot in Python for image generation and when I run a command and someone else try running the same command it only works for the first person. I have tried a lot of things and the logging does go through after the first command goes through but since the defer doesn't work it doesn't work

Code:

```
import io
import json
import discord
from discord import ActionRow, app_commands
from discord.app_commands import Choice
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import SelectMenu, SelectOption
import os
import asyncio
from sd_requests import request
from loggingChannel import sendLog

intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, guild_messages=True,
                          guild_reactions=True, members=True, reactions=True, presences=True)
intents.message_content = True
intents.reactions = True

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def on_ready(self):

        # Get the guild object
        guild_ids = [786690956514426910,
                     254779349352448001, 885595844999532624]

        for guild_id in guild_ids:
            print("Syncing trees for guild {guild_id}")
            await tree.sync(guild=client.get_guild(guild_id))
        print("Synced trees")

        # Loaded
        print('{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
        await updateStatus()

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        # Update Status
        await updateStatus()

        # Log message
        print(
            f'{message.author.name} [{message.author.id}] sent: {message.content} on Channel: {message.channel.id}')


async def updateStatus():
    global streamers
    with open('status.json') as fs:
        data = json.load(fs)


client = MyClient(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)
myid = '<@1043957906921492562>'

# ================================== #
#           Slash Commands           #
# ================================== #
# Command: /dream
# Description: Dream of an Image
# This should have most of the payload options
# ================================== #
@tree.command(description="Dream of an Image")
async def dream(interaction: discord.Interaction, prompt: str, negative: str = "", easy_negative: bool = True,
                steps: int = 20, seed: int = -1, cfg_scale: int = 7, width: int = 512, height: int = 640):

    allowed_channels = [1037159447870590998, 1178374572660244632]
    if interaction.channel.id not in allowed_channels:
        await interaction.response.send_message("Sorry, you may only use the bot in specific channels.")
        return
    else:

        # Dream
        print(await sendLog(log=f'{interaction.user.name} dreaming of {prompt}', client=client))

        await interaction.response.defer()

        # Nerf dangerous commands
        if steps > 50:
            steps = 50
        if width > 800:
            width = 800
        if height > 800:
            height = 800
        if width < 100:
            width = 100
        if height < 100:
            height = 100
        if steps < 1:
            steps = 1

        negative += "lowres, bad anatomy, bad hands, text, error, missing fingers, extra digit, fewer digits, cropped, worst quality, low quality, normal quality, jpeg artifacts, signature, watermark, username, blurry, artist name"

        # Add the command to the queue
        payload = {
            "inputs": prompt,
            "is_negative": False,
            "negative_prompt": "low quality",
            "steps": 1,
            "cfg_scale": 6,
            "seed": None
        }

        # Add the command to the queue
        print("main.py: "+interaction.user.name)
        await request(interaction, payload, "txt2img", defer=True)

# Run the bot with its token
client.run('MTE3NjQwMDQ5NzM4OTg2NzE1MQ.Gyu-z-.OSoEOl07ZCVRGbwDK7n-YtQ8wCYmYgyOGBq7hg')
```

I have tried adding defer to be the first thing and much more.

Comment: New news it just doesn't run until after but the defer thing and stuff and it doesn't run the Image because  the interaction no longer exists.

Comment: You just posted your bot token, meaning that anyone now has access to your bot and all it's servers. To revoke and generate a new one, you can go to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) > Bot > Build-A-Bot > Reset token.